# How do I select elements of an two array given condition?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a 3 numpy arrays

`x1 = [5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5]`
`x2 = [8,14,22,33,0,7]`
`y = [0,0,1,0,1,1]`

I want to select the elements in x1 when y==0 and in x2 when y==1
`output = [5,2,22,1,0,7]`

What is the most efficient way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `numpy.where`:

```
np.where(y, x2, x1)
```

Output:

```
array([ 5,  2, 22,  1,  0,  7])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `masking` and simple element-wise addition

```py
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5])

x2 = np.array([8,14,22,33,0,7])

y = np.array([0,0,1,0,1,1]).astype(bool)

output = x1*~y + x2*y
```

```
array([ 5,  2, 22,  1,  0,  7])
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of list, instead of np.array, you can use:

```
[x2[i] if v else x1[i] for i,v in enumerate(y)]
#[5, 2, 22, 1, 0, 7]
```